# Move multiple objects in bluej

Tags: java, bluej

I am using BLUEJ to create some basic objects etc.
I have 4 objects (3 rectangle and one triangle individual) and I am wanting to use "slowMoveHorizontal" method to move these 4 objects about 50px to the right.

So far, everything works BUT the issue is that they do NOT move together simultaneously. They move on a ONE BY ONE basis.

```
public class PLFlag
{
    private MyRectangle greenRectangle;
    private MyRectangle whiteRectangle;
    private MyRectangle blackRectangle; 
    private MyRectangle frame;
    private MyRectangle mast; 
    private Triangle redTriangle;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class PLFlag
     */
    public PLFlag()
    {
        // nothing to do... instance variables are automatically set to null
    }

    /**
     * Draw this PLFlag.
     */
    public void draw()
    {
        mast = new MyRectangle();
        mast.makeVisible();
        mast.changeSize(400,5);
        mast.changeColor("black");
        mast.moveVertical(-100);
        mast.moveHorizontal(-55);

        frame = new MyRectangle();
        frame.changeColor("black");

        frame.changeSize(122,180);
        frame.slowMoveHorizontal(-50);
        frame.moveVertical(-100);
        frame.makeVisible();

        greenRectangle = new MyRectangle();
        greenRectangle.changeColor("green");

        greenRectangle.changeSize(40,179);
        greenRectangle.moveHorizontal(-50);
        greenRectangle.slowMoveVertical(-19);
        greenRectangle.makeVisible();

        whiteRectangle = new MyRectangle();
        whiteRectangle.changeColor("white");

        whiteRectangle.changeSize(40,179);
        whiteRectangle.moveVertical(-59);
        whiteRectangle.moveHorizontal(-50);     
        whiteRectangle.makeVisible();

        redTriangle = new Triangle();
        redTriangle.changeSize(-90,-120);
        redTriangle.changeColor("red");

        redTriangle.slowMoveHorizontal(210);
        redTriangle.slowMoveVertical(-130);     
        redTriangle.makeVisible();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: If you want help on StackOverflow you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Bajal i posted it

Answer (score 0):

Your has code waits until the `slowMove`s finishes so it can continue. 
You need to let the slowMove run parallelly in a seperate Thread.

Put this code around **each** `slowMoveXXX()` call.

```
new Thread()
{
    public void run() {
        //slowMove here. E.g.:
        greenRectangle.slowMoveVertical(-19);
    }
}.start();
```

Also you need to add the keyword `final` to each object that you use inside the Thread. 
E.g. `private final MyRectangle greenRectangle;` if you need to move the green rectangle slowly.

And btw you probably need to call `makeVisible()` before the slow movement, otherwise you can't see it while it moves.

EDIT: Untested complete code:

```
 public class PLFlag {
 private final MyRectangle greenRectangle;
 private MyRectangle whiteRectangle;
 private MyRectangle blackRectangle;
 private final MyRectangle frame;
 private MyRectangle mast;
 private final Triangle redTriangle;


 /**
  * Constructor for objects of class PLFlag
  */
 public PLFlag() {
  // nothing to do... instance variables are automatically set to null
 }

 /**
  * Draw this PLFlag.
  */
 public void draw() {
  mast = new MyRectangle();
  mast.changeSize(400, 5);
  mast.changeColor("black");
  mast.moveVertical(-100);
  mast.moveHorizontal(-55);
  mast.makeVisible();

  frame = new MyRectangle();
  frame.changeColor("black");
  frame.changeSize(122, 180);
  frame.makeVisible();
  new Thread() {
   public void run() {
    frame.slowMoveHorizontal(-50);
   }
  }.start();
  frame.moveVertical(-100);

  greenRectangle = new MyRectangle();
  greenRectangle.changeColor("green");
  greenRectangle.changeSize(40, 179);
  greenRectangle.moveHorizontal(-50);
  greenRectangle.makeVisible();
  new Thread() {
   public void run() {
    greenRectangle.slowMoveVertical(-19);
   }
  }.start();

  whiteRectangle = new MyRectangle();
  whiteRectangle.changeColor("white");
  whiteRectangle.changeSize(40, 179);
  whiteRectangle.moveVertical(-59);
  whiteRectangle.moveHorizontal(-50);
  whiteRectangle.makeVisible();

  redTriangle = new Triangle();
  redTriangle.changeSize(-90, -120);
  redTriangle.changeColor("red");
  redTriangle.makeVisible();
  new Thread() {
   public void run() {
    redTriangle.slowMoveHorizontal(210);
   }
  }.start();
  new Thread() {
   public void run() {
    redTriangle.slowMoveVertical(-130);
   }
  }.start();
 }
}
```

Comment: i dont know what u mean in the slowMove method

Comment: I mean this for example: `frame.slowMoveHorizontal(-50);`

Comment: yeah but i want to move it together not one by one

Comment: Yeah it will move them togheter if you put each slowMove in an own Thread. Then it does the movements parallelly at the same time.

Comment: could u please give me the code that i should write 
thnx a lot for helping

Comment: Did it work? Btw you coult put the Thread stuff in a function (with object, distance and direction as parameters) so the code gets cleaner.

Comment: can i use arraylist? put in it the objects that i need and then move them? 
could u gimme that functions's code?

Comment: Just put all you Rectangles and other Shapes in a Arraylist, then use a foreach loop and do the thread stuff inside that loop.  I'm not going to write that for you.... It' s your homework after all.

Comment: I created an arralylist and did what to u Saïd but cant do  the method slowmove on it :( yup thnx for all what u did for me its great help ^,^